# Most efficient way to delete all rows on an ArcGIS Online feature layer with ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-online, enterprise

I have a feature layer that needs to be updated monthly. I have been doing it manually on ArcGIS Pro but to be more efficient, I am moving it to Python. In order to not mess with dashboards, I delete all rows on the feature layer and append the new data. I've use delete.row_management and it does the job but being an enterprise item of 88,000 features, it takes a while to delete all of them on a live item and it may confuse live users. Is there a faster method of deleting all rows on a feature layer hosted on enterprise?

Comment: Is this a DataStore table or an enterprise geodatabase table? `arcpy.management.TruncateTable(in_table)` should be near instantaneous, but then the Append could load for a while. Where possible, I load the data into a staging table and use a single `UPDATE`  to manifest the data changes (or a combination of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE computed in advance). The last time I tried this in Python, loading 30 time slices per US county (94k+ rows) took 700-1300 milliseconds (vice using the Python API for ArcGIS, which took 2-3 minutes). I rarely use DELETE if I can INSERT/UPDATE instead,.

Comment: @Vince thank you Vince, I am not sure but it is a normal feature layer hosted within enterprise. I don't know the technical terms but I am going to try this method, and will see if I can find more info about what you suggested. I am not a fan of my current method but it was the easiest way to avoid redoing all the dashboards or using arcgis assistant to point to a new item id.

Comment: Quick note - your question is confusing because the title references ArcGIS Online, but in the body and comments you talk about Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

According [to this post on the Esri community](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/truncate-agol-table-from-pro/td-p/725327), you can run the [Truncate tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/truncatetable.htm) from ArcGIS Pro 3.0+ (ie. arcpy) on Hosted Feature Services. As @Vince says in the comments, Truncate is the best/fastest way to delete all rows. Further [info here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcgis-pro-truncate-table-gp-tool-could-work-on/idc-p/1274485/highlight/true#M24195) verifies this works with Online hosted feature services, possibly with some caveats, like sync must be *disabled*. However, there should be no difference between Online and Enterprise based services. The tool should work on them equally.